Is it possible to play The Witcher 3 DLC from another account by making it primary on my PS4?
I have The Witcher 3 base game on my PSN account, and my friend only has the The Witcher 3 DLC but doesn't have the game on his account.
Can I play the DLC if I set his account as primary on my PS4? (He doesn't own the game, only the DLC, and his account is US region while mine is EU region.)

Yes, you can.
I did the same with Spiderman for PS4, I borrowed the physical copy of the game and my friend owned the DLCs.
You probably don't even need to make his account as primary, it should be enough to have his account logged while you install and start the game.
The different region shouldn't be a problem, either. I have a secondary account to buy games from US store, and I can play them with my EU main account.
